# Started using git recently ... just noticed clones of my files with ' ~ ' appended in the end... why is this happening

Tags: git, commit, ignore

I used git to commit changes in my repository,

followed these steps

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

but noticed a clone of the file where changes were made also present in the repository
new file had '`~`' symbol appended at the end.

why did this happen ? And how can I prevent it in the future ?
Also some thoughts on how to remove the file with "~" would be great

Thanks

Comment: Are you using vim, emacs or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your editor is generating backup files of the form FILENAME~. (Emacs does this; it can be persuaded otherwise.) You have not asked git to ignore files ending in ~. With `git add .` you're telling git to add everything that you haven't asked it to ignore.

See also:
[gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: i think emacs uses another form also wich is #filename#

Answer (score 8):

To complete [bendin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801840/started-using-git-recently-just-noticed-clones-of-my-files-with-appende/801860#801860), add in your working directory a `.gitignore` file with for instance:

```
*~
*.bak
*.old
```

That .gitignore file will have to be added and committed in order to persist through '`git clone`', since there are [several levels of 'gitignore'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore/653495#653495).

Answer (score 0):

> Also some thoughts on how to remove the file with "~" would be great

With gitignore you ignore files that are not yet being tracked, but if you added a file, and later matched it in your .gitignore, it will still be marked as updated when it content changes.

So, the way to remove it from future commits, is using:

```
git rm *~
```

In the other hand, if you want to remove the temp files from old commits, you should look at [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). Be careful if you've published your repo, as this commands rewrites the history, so backup your repo and be aware of what you're doing if you choose this way.