# Using git for the first time

Tags: git, version-control

I want to add a project which is located in my documents into a git repository, is this do-able? Thanks, I've never used git before

Comment: How far have you got? What have you read? Are you stuck, or are you just asking if it's even possible, or worth trying? (The short answer is yes.)

Comment: I removed the "svn" tag from your posts since this has nothing to do with svn. Please only add relevant tags to your posts.

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes:

```
cd yourRep
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

You might want to add a `.gitignore` first in order to not add *every* file in your directory.
Some of them might not be relevant: see ["Started using git recently … just noticed clones of my files with ' ~ ' appended in the end… why is this happening"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801840/started-using-git-recently-just-noticed-clones-of-my-files-with-appende) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Start by navigating to the root folder of your project. Once you are there execute `git init` to initialize a git repository in place. This repository is empty. You will have to add the necessary resources before you can commit them.

Start with `git add -i`. This is an interactive way of adding new resources to the repository.  If you wish to add *all* files then execute `git add .` instead. It would be a good idea to create a `.gitignore` file, add the patterns of unnecessary files to it and then do `git add .`

Once you are done, execute `git commit`.

Answer (score 0):

[free book](http://book.git-scm.com/)

[online and or buy book](http://progit.org/book/)