# Ignoring a directory from a Git repo after it's been added

Tags: git, gitignore

I've learned [how to exclude an entire directory in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory/1470664#1470664) (add a line `bin/` to `.gitignore`). And I've learned [how to ignore files "after the fact"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/git-how-to-ignore-files-in-git/4308645#4308645) (i.e. after they have been added to git):

```
git rm --cached <filename>
```

How do I ignore an entire **directory** (e.g. `bin/`) *after* it has been added to a Git repo?

I tried `git rm --cached bin/` but all I received was the error:

> fatal: pathspec 'bin/' did not match any files

When I tried (at the root directory, where .git exists) `git rm --cached MyProj/bin/` the error is different:

> fatal: not removing 'MyProj/bin/'
>   recursively without -r

What does this mean and will I need to commit and/or branch this now?

Comment: Note the `-r` tag in my answer. You have to use that for `recursive` :)

Comment: @melee It worked! But now I have another question(s). See update. :)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I was able to get this working with `git rm -r --cached bin/` (note the recursive `-r`)in the root of the repo - are you talking about *finding* the bin directories and untracking them?

You will have to `commit` before the exclusion is reflected.

I just saw that you were on Windows. This was in Terminal on OSX, just a heads up.

Comment: Yes, I am on windows but I am using Cygwin which provides an entire Unix-like experience... See my update above. I am not sure I understand what you mean by "finding". I really have only one `bin/` subdirectory under my project. The `.git` directory however is a sibling of my project's directory (i.e. entire git tracking starts one directory above, which could contain several projects). Thanks and +1 for the insights.

Comment: Hmm. Here's an idea; touch or edit one of the files in the bin dir and then try got status. If that is working, they should no longer be tracking.

Comment: @WinWin sorry about that, I was on my phone and missed part of your edit. Glad you were able to get it figured out!

Comment: Eclipse Egit ALERT: I tried this with the bash and committed with the GUI. The problem recurred. Learning: commit with bash/shell when doing above. :) Cheers!

Comment: I've tried `git rm -r --cached <folder_name>` in the root folder (which contains the .git folder), and I still receive the error `fatal: pathspec 'folder_name' did not match any files`. This is especially strange since I had been able to press 'tab' to autocomplete the folder's name. I am using Terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: @haopei: It happen when your bin directory is empty, or it's untracked folder. Pls check by <code>git status</code>.

Comment: Thanks @ducanhng -- Add untracked folder before ignoring it by `git add folder/.`

Comment: worked for me it already assumes your at the root directory so you can literally put a folder name or file within the parent folder and it will remove it.

Answer (score 12):

On windows:

```
git rm -r --cached ./FOLDERNAME/
```

And then do the other stuffs. (`add` and `commit` and `push`)

(Note that on windows you should use `./` before the folder name, just like above.)