# Intellij IDEA still shows changes that are ignored

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore, intellij-14

Using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.14, I ignored the some folders (They are completely gray), but Intellij still shows the changes in "Local Changes". [IMAGE 3]

The folders have a gray name [IMAGE 1] and the folders are added to the .gitignore file [IMAGE 2].

I added them by rightclicking the folder and clicking "Add to .gitignore file".

Why does it still show this changes?

[image: Help]

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIT ignore files which are on repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231608/git-ignore-files-which-are-on-repository)

Comment: My files do not exist on the github repo. (They did but I removed them in a commit). I'll try the solution.

Comment: Which command should I use for 2 folders?

Comment: You should check any of those files with `git status` to check if they are present in your repo. If they are, you can see how to use `git rm` and `git update-index` on folders in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618612/ignoring-a-directory-from-a-git-repo-after-its-been-added) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288212/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-on-directory) questions respectively.

Comment: It did not work. C:\Users\p6340nl\Desktop\NetBeans projects\UltimateCore>git rm -r --cached  scr/bammerbom/ultimatecore/spongeapi_old
fatal: pathspec 'scr/bammerbom/ultimatecore/spongeapi_old' did not match any files

Comment: Enter's don't work in comments -_-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted the .git directory and let git recreate it. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the files have been removed from the git index but not yet committed.   For example, if you only did:

`git rm --cached file.txt`

to remove them from the repo you'll need to follow up with a commit.  As noted in the comments above, if you do `git status` you might see your files marked as

```
Changes to be committed: 
      deleted:    file.txt
```