# .gitignore is not working on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I used to develop on linux environment, but now I need to write a git project on "windows" os. I need to ignore a directory from where the git is initiated.

like `folder/.git/`, now I need to ignore `/folder/project/bin/*`. So I have added .gitignore file on `folder/.gitignore` using both text pad and Visual studio.

.gitignore file contents are

```
/project/bin/*
```

Now, I expect `git status` should not show `/project/bin` folder.

Note, I have tried other ways too, but it seems that git is considering the .gitignore file as a general text file or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but I suspect that the leading forward-slash is throwing something off.  I'm not sure about the trailing star either (as I reference my own .gitignore files).

Your .gitignore should be this:

```
project/bin/
```

Comment: Tried that too. I have found some says about the .gitignore file's font encoding issue(Unicode is not supported). I don't have a clear idea about that. Thanks.

Comment: Open the .gitignore with Windows Notepad and select `File->Save As`.  The bottom of the file-save dialog will have an Encoding box. Select **ANSI**.

Comment: @selbie - In my case "*" was not working, your comment was the actual answer for me.

Comment: @selbie's solution was the only one worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I frustratingly found the same issue. I couldn't seem to ignore folders, but files were OK. My issue started with folders that contain spaces.  All the combinations I could find after a searching (full directory path, trying to ignore case, escaping the spaces, etc) didn't resolve it.

I had to remove spaces in directory names, then I was able to ignore files.
I tried it on WSL (Windows sub-system for Linux - git was already installed), no problems.

Then reading more, I realised that if files are previously tracked, then the .gitignore won't work.  I tested it by deleting all the files in the directory, then adding the directory to .gitignore `path/to/my_files/*.csv` (in my case I'm ignoring data in .csv files) and doing a commit then push (good job this is just dev).

After that worked, I was able to use `git rm -r --cached ./path/to/my_files/` to un track all the files in another directory rather than cutting and pasting them back ([Thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63234942/10407448))

So:

1. Un-track all the files
2. Add the directory in .gitignore (In windows it wasn't case sensitive)
3. add/commit/push as normal.