# What is the best way to hide database login information for public collaboration on GitHub?

Tags: php, mysql, git, github, hash

So I have plans to work on a website with some people that I do not know, on GitHub. For websites that I have created in the past, I have stored my credentials in a file called db-const.php, and included them when needed.

The problem that I am having is, the host that the website will on is not the same host as my mySQL database, so I cannot simply use localhost-only credentials. I would perfer to not have to censor my credientials every time I commit.

My idea so far is to create a php file on **my** host that delivers the data in a hashed format when called for, which is then unhashed on retrieval. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called (something like) `localsettings.php` which has the *local to the server* settings only as `define(key,value)`. This would be only the login, password, database name etc. details - nothing else.

Use the `key` (which I'm guessing you are already using) in your code.

Make the permissions for `localsettings.php` read only (to prevent accident overwrites).

On the GitHub code, include a blank version of `localsettings.php` which includes a comment to include the `define(key,value)` that are local for the server the code will be used on. Also include info that the file should be marked *read only* so it does not need to be updated with each sync.

You can also [ignore a list of files with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git) if the read only permissions are a problem.