# Only push certain files once

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repository for a server.
That server needs some files, but these files only have to be pushed once.
So when someone edits it, then it doesn't have to be pushed to github, but when someone downloads the repository they should get the unedited file.

The server needs these files to run, but for every person are these files different, that's why I don't want it to be pushed again.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't committed the files yet, i'd say add the filename to your `.gitignore` file like:

`<filename>.<extension>`

So in case the file is package.json:

`package.json`

Wildcards can be made by using the *

`*.json`

or as [AoeAoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882600/aoeaoe) remarked: you can add the file later using `git add --force` to overrule the `.gitignore` file.

Now if the content of your file is merely 10 rules of config, i'd say: create a mock-up out of it and write it down in your `readme.md` and instruct your colleagues to create their own, otherwise, you should follow the advice in the update section.

**Update:** as [Edward Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) stated: *.gitignore doesn't apply to uploaded files* you'll be forced to use `git update-index`

To force the file from not updating:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`

To enable updating again:

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file`

Comment: So I just commit it for the first time and after that I add them to the .gitignore file? that's it?

Comment: Yes! That should do the trick, it would be wise to commit the gitignore file before anyone else starts working and branching, so you're for sure everyone uses this gitignore file.

Comment: You can always add them later, .gitignore can be overriden with `git add --force`. This answer is correct though.

Comment: Ah, this is usefull to know, I'll update the answer with your comment, thanks!

Comment: If you've committed it to your repository, `.gitignore` doesn't work.  `.gitignore` _only_ applies to untracked files.

Comment: But that would leave it still open for `git update-index` wouldn't it?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I'm assuming this is now correct, would you mind peer-reviewing this answer?

Answer (score 1):

These files changes should be ignored by git remote repository, since they need a local management. You have to add the path of these files to .gitignore file. If you have already committed and pushed original version of your files, when someone clones the repository, it will receive the original files without any local changes.

[How to add gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file)

[How to ignore certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

It's better practice to remove file from index[1]:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Purpose of .gitignore is to never track and never add a file to index in the first place.

[1] [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: This is not really what I was looking for, thanks, though. Might come in handy later.

Comment: That's not really what he wants though, he wants to have it in but ignore it in commits. Force adding it along with .gitignore inclusion is a way to go here, this is common practice when you want to distribute binaries in your repo but you don't want to bother with them every time people recompile their tree.