# Git Pull rebase without loosing generated files / ignoring generated files

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-pull

> How to pull and rebase without loosing generated files
>
> When I just use pull, it creates a new merge commit. To avoid that, we need to use --rebase switch.
>
> But if I use --rebase switch, it will override the generated files.
>
> How to overcome this issue

Comment: What do you mean by "generated files"?

Comment: For example, I have a server.xml template which will be updated or overridden once I open my editor (say eclipse / netbeans, etc). In this case if I do git pull --rebase, this will be lost and I have to rerun my commands to get this.

Comment: Is your `server.xml` file in source control? Do you want it to be in source control? Can you see if this SO question has the information you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git

Comment: It is not a particular server.xml It is just for an example. There are other lot of files like that