# unable to get git to ignore a previously tracked file

Tags: git

I was tracking a file in `git`, but don't want to track it anymore

```
± |master ↑1 ?:1 ✗| → git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    data/foo.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

± |master U:1 ?:1 ✗| → git update-index --assume-unchanged data/foo.txt
fatal: Unable to mark file data/foo.txt

± |master U:1 ?:1 ✗| → git rm --cached data/foo.txt
fatal: pathspec 'data/foo.txt' did not match any files
```

How do I convince `git` to ignore `data/foo.txt`?

Comment: Do you know about `.gitignore`?

Comment: hmm, thanks. Didn't occur to me to add data/foo.txt to .gitignore. Did, and now it is ignored, eh! Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore certain files in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)