# When I am trying to push code on Git it shows errors

Tags: xcode, git

In xcode it shows like below image. I am trying to push my code. But I dont know what is missing by me.

[image]

Comment: Have you added this files to the repository?

Comment: That is the biggest confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode by default makes an initial commit once a new project gets created. The purpose of it is to keep a version of the project at its initial state. That happens behind the scenes, without disturbing you or asking for any kind of confirmation from you. If you don’t add a git repository when creating a new project, but you do so later manually as shown in the previous part, the initial commit is preformed with the command: git commit -m ‘Initial commit’ that we previously used.

Actually, you can see information regarding the initial commit if you go to the Source Control > History… menu. In there is recorded every commit you perform to the project.

[image]

If you select the Discard Change option on the menu, a confirmation window will appear notifying that the selected change will be reverted, and there’s no way to undo that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems those files are not allowed in git, try to add extension's files to git ignore and try it again. Here you can see an example of how to do that [How to ignore certain files in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)