# Stop git from picking up background changes in project

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am new to git and am using the github desktop software. Everytime I make a change in my project lots of other files which get changed in the background also appear in the changes section of git. How would I stop git from picking up these changes, as I only want to upload the code I am editing. Thanks!
https://gyazo.com/e28007bbb220d22511deabf236f569bb

Comment: `.gitignore` will be your friend, I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore certain files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `.gitignore` file at the root of your project and list the folders and files you don't want git to track like this:

```
.idea
bin/
```

You can find many examples on this git repository if you don't want to do it manually: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

you can use gitignore in you git folder.
Within this file you can specify what files you dont want to have tracked.

Make sure you name your gitignore like this:

```
.gitignore
```

Documentaion for gitignore:
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Here your can create your .gitignore for your programming language:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore

Cheers