# Where to store my API key in an open source Python Script

Tags: python, api-key

So I'm working on with an api from [IsThereAnyDeals](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/) and I'm wondering where I should store my API key? Is it possible to store it remotely or is it fine to just store it inside the script?

Comment: Neither.  Store it outside the script and have the script read from the file(which isn't stored in any repository).

Comment: You only need to store it remotely (securely on the host server) if you’re going to deploy it somewhere. Otherwise keep it a “secret” (local file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is a good choice to setup your configuration-files in Python.

Something like this:

```
import configparser

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('example.cfg')

print(cfg.get('KEYS', 'api_key', raw=''))
```

`example.cfg`:

```
[KEYS]
api_key: @#$@GSSAS
```

Comment: My API key will still be exposed. It that okay?

Comment: Of course you shouldnt be uploading the `example.cfg`! Thats only for your instance

Answer (score 1):

You can add your cfg file to .gitignore, so that this file doesn't get uploaded, when you do a git commit.

You can read more about that topic here: [How to ignore certain files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)