# Push large file without git lfs

Tags: swift, git, github, realm

I try to commit changes to my project on github. I have added Realm Database to my project and commit is too big now. I have read that I need to use github large file, but to do this I need to install homebrew on my mac. The problem is that I don't have enough memory to do this.

I found an article on github where people recommend to install Realm via Xcode swift package manager (now I use cocoa pods) and then it should not be as large. But I wonder if there is a problem to use cocoa pods (I need it for few other thins) and swift package manager in one project?

When I try to commit I have this alerts

```
Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/watchos-armv7k_arm64_32/librealm-monorepo.a is 76.01 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB

Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64_i386-simulator/librealm-monorepo.a is 68.40 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB

Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/tvos-arm64_x86_64-simulator/librealm-monorepo.a is 53.93 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB

Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/librealm-monorepo.a is 77.82 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

Comment: "The problem is that I don't have enough memory to do this." At which point this becomes a hardware issue. If you have so little memory, you are already hosed. This is not a viable development environment.

Comment: You shouldn't commit your checked out dependencies to git in the first place. Look into what you should and shouldn't commit to git when using Cocoapods.

Comment: Put your large files in your ignore list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, homebrew is not so large that you are likely to run out of storage space (I'm assuming you meant storage, not memory).

Also, you can choose to commit certain files only. You can refer to this answer - [Git: How to ignore certain files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/git-how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git).

Lastly, there should not be any issue with using Cocoapods and Swift Package Manager together. I have multiple projects that do this and have not encountered any problems at all.