# Is it possible to `git add` a file currently protected by `assume-unchanged`?

Tags: git

I have certain files that I rarely want new versions committed on but change often due to IDE settings.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged meta.xml
```

Is it possible to forcibly `git add meta.xml` without having to apply `no-assume-unchanged` first?

Comment: I think there's `-f` flag. It certainly works for normally ignored files

Comment: Yeah, it does work on ignored files, but I tried it here. It had no effect. I'm just hoping I can manually add files without having to turn this protection off each individual time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible: both `git update-index --assmue-unchanged` and `git update-index --skip-worktree` would make a git add impossible.

That leaves you with the definition of an alias, which would:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
git add -- theFile
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Something along the lines of:

```
addf = "!f() { git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- $1; git add -- $1; git update-index --assume-unchanged -- $1}; f
```