# Stop tracking files in git (without deleting them)

Tags: git

I have a file in Git which I have made private modifications to. I want to keep the file in Git but don't want to check in my private modifications to it.

Currently I just don't include that file when I run `git add` but I'd rather not even see that in the list of modified files.  Is there any way to do that?

P.S. .gitignore doesn't work because I have to delete the file from the repository to stop it from being tracked.  I want the file to stay there but not contain my private changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the answer is pretty simple.

Just run `git update-index --skip-worktree [path]` to stop git from tracking changes to any given file.

If you ever do make changes to that file which you want to commit with git, run `git update-index --no-skip-worktree [path]` to make git start tracking that file again

---

FYI: The original answer suggested using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` but it turns out that option can break behavior when switching branches, while --skip-worktree is intended for this exact scenario. More details here: [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree)

Comment: Beware of checkout or pull though. read the second part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/653495/6309

Comment: More details on difference between --skip-worktree and --assume-unchanged: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree

Comment: @ZainRizvi This will only work for my local clone of the repo. Is there a way to make this behavior happen automatically for all devs?

Comment: @MauriR not that I know of. You'd need to setup some git config file and share that with all your devs to make this somewhat automatic