# Ignoring files without editing .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have cloned project with it's `.gitignore`. Then I have placed some directories with files in it used for specific testing purposes. I don't want commit these directories to remote repository but I also don't place strange directories and files names to `.gitignore` in order not disturb other developers who will read `.gitignore`. How to solve such problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Git ignore files without using .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple levels of git ignore configurations. You can e. g. edit `.git/info/exclude` and define your excludes there. You can also make a user-specific excludes file that is then in effect for all or your git repositories, ...

For more info read `man gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably each IDE have option for exclude some folders, for example into **PHP Storm** you can use option **Mark Directory as Excluded**.

Also before commit you can add only files which should be commited, using:

```
git add name_of_file1 name_of_file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a local .gitignore_global file for this purpose.
With this file you will be able to ignore your tests files for this project and the next ones.

- Create a file here: `~/.gitignore_global`
- Add your ignored files in it.
- Then then run this command: `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

More informations here https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore.

Comment: " for this project and the next ones" - I don't like "next ones", because in this case it is possible that in other project, project directory might have the same name like in current project testing directory.