# Don't update and track changes of local file while not adding to .gitignore

Tags: git

I have file `tst.properties` that I would like not update from git remote repository. Also I would like not commit it to remote while not editing `.gitignore`. I don't want edit `.gitignore`because other team members don't follow defined constant `tst.properties` rule. How to protect this file from update from remote and not track changes before commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Git ignore files without using .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore)

Comment: @JulienLopez this is not the right duplicate as OP wants to ignore changes to a tracked file incoming and outgoing

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, not even **with** editing `.gitignore` or one of its relatives. A tracked file is a tracked file is a tracked file. You cannot make Git ignore changes to a tracked file that come in from remote or changes you did locally. If a file is tracked it is tracked, fullstop.

You might read somewhere about `--assume-unchanged` to ignore local changes to a tracked file, but this is a dangerous option, as then Git thinks the file is always unchanged locally and will overwrite the file if you change branches or get in changes from remote, effectively loosing your local changes as for Git there are no local changes.

The right technique is to delete `tst.properties` from the repository and add it to `.gitignore`, adding a file `tst.properties.sample` that people can copy locally to `tst.properties` and modify to suit their needs, or to add a second layer of files, so that in `tst.properties` the defaults are defined and tracked and you can have a second file `tst-local.properties` that is in `.gitignore` and can be used to overwrite settings from `tst.properties`. For the latter option the software that evaluates the file has to be changed to support this of course.