# how to pull the specific folder from github repository

Tags: github, magento2

I am working on magento. beginning of the project I have installed magento 2 on **windows laptop** and worked on it.later I made one repository in git and pushed the code to git.

now I got the one **Ubuntu** production server.I have cloned that git repository.due to platform changes I have run the command **"composer install"**  and changed some configuration .so here is the problem from next on words when I pull the repository from git hub it should pull only one folder named **app**  from git hub

If all files pulled from git hub, **configuration files** will be changed so it won't work again in my Ubuntu server.

I hope **magento developers** are more familiar with this.please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: So instead the configuration files should go in `.gitignore` but that will also delete the files from your git repo.

Comment: Yeah I have tried.but it's deleting files from git repo.

Comment: Generally we keep and example files of config in the repo. Like in rails we have a database.yml so we keep database.yml.example in the repo and the database.yml in gitignore. Would this be possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the same issue, you will have to follow below steps:

Step 1- git init

Step 2- git remote add [REMOTE_NAME] [GIT_URL]

Step 3- git fetch REMOTE_NAME

Step 4- git checkout REMOTE_NAME/BRANCH -- path/to/directory

Answer (score 0):

**How to ignore new files**

*Globally*

Add the path(s) to your file(s) which you would like to ignore to your .gitignore file (and commit them). These file entries will also apply to others checking out the repo.

*Locally*

Add the path(s) to your file(s) which you would like to ignore to your .git/info/exclude file. These file entries will only apply to your local working copy.

**How to ignore changed files (temporarily)**

In order to ignore changed files to being listed as modified, you can use the following git command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

To **revert** that ignorance use the following command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Read More from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/653495/6107715