# How to set up a .gitignore that is not tracked?

Tags: git

I often have extra files that I want to gitignore but I don't want to push the .gitignore with my ignores in it since it pollutes the team's code repo as those ignore are technically just for.

Is there a way to have a local ignore just for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/653489/421195): "There are three ways to tell Git which files to ignore - `.gitignore` files, 2) `$GIT_DIR/.git/info/exclude`, 3)
Files pointed to via the `core.excludesfile` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two options for this.  This is a great option for files that are specific to your situation, such as editor-specific files, that you want to ignore but aren't universally applicable

If the files you want to ignore are specific to your project, you can use `.git/info/exclude`.  That's specific to your repo.

If the files you want to ignore are general across all repos, you can use `core.excludesFile`, which defaults to `~/.config/git/ignore`.

You can see both of these uses with `git help gitignore`.