# git assume-unchaged with .vscode/ not working

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've locally changed my `.vscode/settings.json` (added some user vocabulary). I don't want to merge this to the shared repo, but it's annoying me because git keeps tracking it.

I don't want to edit `.gitignore` because I would also have to make the push to the shared repo.

I tried using the `--assume-unchanged` flag but it's not working:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged .vscode/` returns:
`Ignoring path .vscode/`.

But when I log `git status` afterwards, I still get

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .vscode/
```

If I try with `git update-index --assume-unchanged .vscode/settings.json`, I get `fatal: Unable to mark file .vscode/settings.json`.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: add the settings.json to gitignore? that way it will ignore it unless you want it tracked again which is when you delete it from gitignore again

Comment: hi, I don't want to add it to the gitignore - see my question again pls. I don't want to commit the gitignore either. :)

Comment: oh my bad, have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore

Comment: Nice!! This worked: adding to `.git/info/exclude` .Thanks :)