# How to set git alias in .gitconfig to override default behavior of add command?

Tags: git, git-config

I have a folder that I always want to exclude from staging/commiting to git. I don't want to  add this file to our gitignore. So whenever I stage my changes, I have been using the command `git add . -- ":!./ignoreddir/"`.

I want this to be a default behvior of my 'git add'. So I added the following to my .gitconfig but git says I have 'bad config' on the line.

```
[alias]
add = add -- ":!./ignoreddir/"
```

What's the right way to override the command in git config?

Comment: You cannot define an alias with the name of an existing command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538791/7976758

Comment: You can use `.git/info/exclude` to ignore files/dirs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/653495/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+without+using+%22.gitignore%22

Comment: @phd - thank-you so much. That worked! Such a lovely solution!