# TortoiseGit's equivalent to TortoiseSVN's global ignore patterns

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is there a TortoiseGit equivalent to TortoiseSVN's "global ignore patterns" setting?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640449/git-dont-show-me-pyc-in-the-list-of-untracked-files/640668#640668), git has 3 levels of ignore files.

If you reference one in your `~/.gitconfig`, you can manage your global ignore pattern (even though this is not directly integrated in [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

global ignore patterns are stored in

- **~/.gitconfig**

where **~** is the users home directory.

Some alias examples (which are stored in mentioned files due to the **--global** option):

- git config **--global** alias.co checkout
- git config **--global** alias.br branch
- git config **--global** alias.ci commit
- git config **--global** alias.st status

See git [config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details.